# GTest и TearDown

Tags: c++, gtest

Когда происходит FAIL() тогда TearDown не освобождает ресурсы, можно ли как то сделать чтоб когда - происходит FAIL() происходил вызов деструктора или тип того.

Comment: Деструктор будет вызван.

Comment: я грешил на FAIL, а на самом деле ето вызывался bug()